# Merge two Dataframes with different structures

Tags: python, pandas, data-wrangling

I am trying to combine two dataframes with each other. But I am stuck on the logic (maybe I looked too long to the problem).

**Problem:**
DF1 is in a format like this:

```
Country       ID    March    April  May  June 
Netherlands   A      10       20     15   14 
Netherlands   B      15       18     10    4
Germany       C       9        8      3    1
```

Then, I have another dataframe:

DF2

```
Country      ID    Month   Number
Netherlands  A     March     8  
Netherlands  A     March     28  
Netherlands  B     April     18  
Germany      C     Jan       9
```

I would like to merge these two columns (in the same format as DF1).
My assumption was that is should be something like, group by (Country + ID), and then (Month as column, and SUM the Number). - but as said before, I am confussed.

Desired output:

```
Country       ID    March    April  May  June   df2_Jan  df2_March   df2_April
Netherlands   A      10       20     15   14       0       36 #8+28     0
Netherlands   B      15       18     10    4       0        0          18
Germany       C       9        8      3    1       9        0           0
```

Hope that you can help me. Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Have you looked at this: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pandas-merge-two-dataframes-with-different-columns/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
merged_df = (
    df1.merge(
        df2.pivot_table(
            index=['Country', 'ID'],
            columns='Month',
            values='Number',
            aggfunc=sum,
            fill_value=0)
        .add_prefix('df2_')
        .reset_index(),
        on=['Country', 'ID']
    )
)
```

OUTPUT:

```
       Country ID  March  April  May  June  df2_April  df2_Jan  df2_March
0  Netherlands  A     10     20   15    14          0        0         36
1  Netherlands  B     15     18   10     4         18        0          0
2      Germany  C      9      8    3     1          0        9          0
```

Comment: Shouldn’t aggfunc be `np.sum` ideally (as the default per the docs seems to be `np.mean`) ? That’s also what examples on the pivot_table documentation suggest. I’m not sure why but they don’t seem to be exactly equivalent, see `sum(pd.Series([1, np.nan]))` vs. `np.sum(pd.Series([1, np.nan]))`  for example.

Comment: @Cimbali, I'm filling NaN values with 0. So, I guess it doesn't matter in this particular case.

Answer (score 1):

- Summing in DF2 indeed is a simple `groupby().sum()` operation

  ```
  df2 = df2.groupby(['Country', 'ID', 'Month'])['Number'].sum()
  ```

  You now have a series with 3-level index.
- It seems to make DF2 to the same format as DF1 you only need a single `.unstack()` which pivots one of the index levels to columns.

  ```
  df2 = df2.unstack('Month', fill_value=0)
  ```
- Merging in same format is now easy

  ```
  df1.merge(df2.add_prefix('df2_').reset_index(), on=['Country', 'ID'])
  ```

Steps 1 and 2 can be replace with a single call to `.pivot_table` with the `aggfunc` parameter, as per @Nk03’s answer.

Comment: Appreciate you help! Was checking the answer, but the unstack part is not working "KeyError: 'Level Number not found'

Comment: @Roverflow it’s unstack of `Month` indeed. It just moves an index level to columns, so you can use the name of the level you want appropriately.